# fixed div overlaps other div in container

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have two divs in a wrapper. One floats left at 20% width, one floats right at 80% width. Both have a max width of 2000px with auto margins in order to center the content. The problem I'm having is that at a larger width, the divs begin to overlap and I cannot figure out how to get them side by side regardless of the width.

Here is my html:

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
</div>
<div class="slider">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Here is my css

```
body
    {
    background-color: #3F3F3F;
    }


.wrapper
    {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; 
    max-width: 2000px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    } 

.container
    { 
    width: 20%;
    background-color:#F6F6F6;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 2000px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    }

    .slider {
        width: 80%; 
        height: 2000px;
        float: right; 
        position: relative;
        background-color: #8A0002;
        opacity: .2;
        max-width: 2000px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        }
```

I'm a student and really appreciate any help!!!

Comment: do you want something like this ?https://jsfiddle.net/7wb8drq5/

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: relative` in `.container`.

With `position: fixed` it seems to calculate the container as the 20% of the width of the wrapper + its margins.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question but, I would like to keep .container fixed as it will contain navigation and .slider will consist of scrolling content.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

*please ignore this answer I kept it for the comment.*

---

You'll need to clear your floats. You can [read more here](http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/).

This is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sgept1o8/) sample of one way to do it.
or you can simple add an element inside your wrapper and clear that one.

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
 clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
 zoom: 1; /* ie 6/7 */
}
```

add this do your CSS and and change your wrapper to `<div class="wrapper clearfix">`

Reference : [Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I followed your instructions and the changes to CSS did not work for me but, I will definitely read more about clearing floats.

Comment: @AdamLeeSFC try this `body {margin:0;}`. Please ignore that fiddle.